# Waiting for data for CellTable in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I'm using GWT 2.4 with `RequestFactory` mechanism. With bigger portions of `data` there is some extra time `(1-2 sec)` for `celltables` to get populated. During that time `celltable` is empty and user doesn't know if anything will appear in it. Is there any way to enable waiting `indicator` for `celltables` for the time they are being populated?

I've already configured waiting indicator for `RequestFactory` calls, so I've got prepared `images` for it, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setLoadingIndicator API of CellTable -

```
cellTable.setLoadingIndicator( Your customised loading indicator widget );
```

Widget can be a image wrapped with in a panel or just an image.

If you are using the ListDataProvider you need to code some more lines. When you do addDataDisplay method call it internally updates the row count to 0. With this Tables's state gets changed to Loaded. So we don't get the loading image.

Workaround is, do addDataDisplay method call only just before the dataProvider.setList call.

Comment: I've added cellTable.setLoadingIndicator(new Image("resources/ajax-loader.gif")); and nothing appeared. Same loader.gif is used for RequestFactory calls and it works fine.

Comment: Are you using the ListDataProvider ?

Comment: do addDataDisplay method call only just before the dataProvider.setList call. Refer updated answer.

Comment: I am not happy with the workaround but it seems there is no other way :(

Comment: But i dont think it is the right programming way. addDataDisplay should be a part of just initialization. It should not update anything like row count.

Answer (score 1):

Before you are calling the `setLoadingIndicator` you have to call the below method

```
cellTable.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(cellTable.getVisibleRange(),
   true);
```